# How I can use my own style in mapboxe using r (mapboxer package)?

Tags: r, mapbox, htmlwidgets

Hi and thanks for reading me. Im trying to use my own style using the mapboxer package in R but it doesn't work and I don't know why, the code im using is the following:

```
library(mapboxer)
style <-"https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/jorgehdez1998/ckviz4pms2thz14pi5zgu0iox.html?title=view&access_token=pk.eyJ1Ijoiam9yZ2VoZGV6MTk5OCIsImEiOiJja2o2dnNyeWUzOGx2MzJteTA1cGp3eHdqIn0.2tlIRcZ5xTzSRR0Pj57G2w&zoomwheel=true&fresh=true#4.5/45.55/3.71"

mapboxer(
     access_token = "my-token",
     style = style,
     center = c(3.71, 45.55),
     zoom = 4.5
)
```

Does anyone can help me? please

## UPDATE

I tried using the following code:

```
mapboxer(style ="mapbox://styles/mapbox/v1/jorgehdez1998",
         token = "pk.eyJ1Ijoiam9yZ2VoZGV6MTk5OCIsImEiOiJja2o2dnNyeWUzOGx2MzJteTA1cGp3eHdqIn0.2tlIRcZ5xTzSRR0Pj57G2w"
         )
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: Have you solved this issue? I have the same problem. Also, I suggest you to edit your post and replace your token by a `my_mapbox_token_here` just for not letting it open.